# input type=date in not working in Internet Explorer 11 for my angular 7 project

Tags: angular, date, internet-explorer, datepicker

i am having trouble to work wit Internet Explorer as input type date in not working with it. i have done many validation and calculation on the project with the dates. What is the best way i cam make it work with Internet Explorer...

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide come code and a minimal reproducable example.

Comment: From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date), we can see that the `<input type="date">` not support IE browser, as a workaround, you could try to use the `<input type="text">` tag, then using [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [JQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) plugin. Besides, you could also try to use the [Angular Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Angular Material date picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

It works on IE11:

[image]